# Pass parent object as child object after checking type

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

What I am trying to do is most easily explained as such:

```
Animal animal = petStore.getRandomAnimal();

if(animal.isDog()){
    kennel.add(animal)
}
```

Obviously I can not do it this way since kennel.add() only accepts type Dog.

I have determined that the animal is a dog, but how do I let the compiler know this?

working in java.

Comment: This question has been marked as duplicate, but this question is not about instanceOf (although that was a handy thing to learn). This question was about casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast the Animal Object to Dog class

```
Animal animal = petStore.getRandomAnimal();

if (animal instanceof Dog) {
    kennel.add((Dog) animal)
}
```